# numpy ndarray object has no attribute append

Tags: python, numpy, loops, numpy-ndarray

I am struggling with a program I am making on the part where I have to store values that I get from my loop in an array.

What I tried to do is to make an empty array called M. Then for every new value "a" calculated in a loop I use the command M.append(a) to add the value a to the array M.

The thing is, python says this error : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
with open('expFcn0.txt') as f:
    M = np.array([])
    print(M)
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
    for i in range(0,181):
        a=np.log(y[i])/x[i]
        print(a)
        i=i+1
        M.append(a)
    print(M)

    
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r--')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Biomass')
    plt.title('Exponential Function')
    plt.show()
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Answers suggest using the `numpy.append` method, but appending to a numpy array is not good practice. You are probably better off creating a python list and appending to that. If you want a numpy array of the results, you can create a numpy array from that list.

Comment: Use `M = []`.  A list has an append, an array does not.

Comment: BTW, if it's not a typo, modify index, ``i=i+1``, doesn't work and should be avoided inside for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy arrays *don't* have a method `append()`. You need to use `np.append(array, values)` as per the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), or for your case, `np.append(M, a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers explain that numpy arrays do not have an `.append()` method and point to `numpy.append`. Using `numpy.append`, however, is bad practice because it creates a new array each time. A better solution is to create one numpy and fill it during the `for` loop (see end of answer).

An even better solution would make use of numpy's broadcasting. That's a core feature of numpy, and it's what helps make numpy fast.

```py
import numpy as np

with open('expFcn0.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = np.array([float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines])
    y = np.array([float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines])

M = np.log(y) / x
```

You can also look into [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to read the file into a numpy array directly.

---

How to fill a numpy array in a `for` loop:

```py
import numpy as np

with open('expFcn0.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]

M = np.zeros(181)
for i in range(181):
    a = np.log(y[i])/x[i]
    print(a)
    M[i] = a
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays do not have an append method. Use the Numpy append function instead:

```
M = np.append(M, a)
```